# Is "Listen Up!" A complete sentence?

Tags: sentence-fragments

Is "Listen up" a complete sentence or is it just a fragment?

Comment: It's a complete sentence.

Comment: It's one word too many. "Listen!" is a sentence which doesn't require "up" to complete it.